# Interfaces or classes when using objects

Tags: c#, .net, interface

In my project I have defined an interface to describe the methods that each of my different database connection classes must have. This is called `IDatabaseConnectivityObject`. Each of my classes implements this interface to make sure that they all contain the same methods for running queries, making connections etc etc.

Consider the following code:

```
IDatabaseConnectivityObject adoDataBaseConnection = new DbProviderFactoryConnection();

DbProviderFactoryConnection adoDataBaseConnection = new DbProviderFactoryConnection();
```

Will the above lines both behave the same? If so why? If not then why not? What are the benefits of both?

It may be a really stupid question but I havent used interfaces all that long and I am not sure what line 1 does. It was my understanding that you couldnt make an instance of an interface as it merely defines behaviour so how is that line possible?

Comment: Read more about [interface programming](https://www.google.com/search?q=interface+programming)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: As a metaphor, why do we need nouns in langauge? This is not really just a c# or .net question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the above lines both behave the same? If so why?

At runtime yes. The difference is that if you declare the variable of type `IDatabaseConnectivityObject` then at compile time you will be able to see only the members of this interface on the variable. If on the other hand you declare it as `DbProviderFactoryConnection` then you will see all the members of this class.

As a good practice it is recommended to always work with the highest possible type in the hierarchy when declaring the variable (`IDatabaseConnectivityObject` in this case) which allows you to access all members that the consumer will need.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that if I have a public member declared in the class that implements the interface that I have in that case no option but to use the line 2 implementation above in order to have access to that member?

Comment: It depends where this member is defined. If it is defined inside the interface then you could still use the first example. If it is defined in the class you need to declare the variable as DbProviderFactoryConnection to have access to this member at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The first would allow you to swap in a different implementation of you `IDatabaseConnectivityObject` moving forward.

This is a good practice as it allows your system to be more resistant to change moving forward. Keeping the cost of change low is key.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces define the contract that consumers can rely on, the API if you will. The two lines are functionally the same if you intend to use members that are present on the interface.

Using the interface just expresses that you don't care how something is implemented, just that it is implemented to contract. Interfaces also promote Loose Coupling.

The benefit of programming against an interface is that you are programming against the "agreement" and not the "execution", or the contract and not the implementation. This has a large positive impact on testing as you can mock or stub interfaces during tests to reduce the number of extraneous dependencies in a test scenario.

A similar benefit to above is that using interfaces along with something like the factory pattern, IoC, or DI you can provide different implementations of the interface on the fly - for example, a different business logic handler for a different customer.

Another benefit is that it helps get around the lack of multiple inheritance. Most things can be expressed nicely via interfaces, and classes can implement multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for benefits.

When you are programming against interfaces (and are using factories to create the concrete types) this makes unit-testing easier as you can mock the instance that is put into the logic (unit).

This is actually a 'Design Pattern Principle':

> "Program to an 'interface', not an 'implementation'." (Gang of Four 1995:18)